# Pomodoro Clock - seconds are not displayed

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the disappearing seconds in Pomodoro timer after clicking on START.

```js
let countdown;

const timerDisplay = document.querySelector('.display_timer');
const start = document.querySelector('[data-action="start"]');
const restart = document.querySelector('[data-action="restart"]')

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (countdown) return;
    timer(1500);
});

function timer(seconds) {
    const now = Date.now();
    const then = now + (seconds * 1000);


    countdown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);
        if (secondsLeft < 0) {
          clearInterval(countdown);
          return;
          timer(1500);
        }
          display_timer(secondsLeft);
      }, 1000);
}
   
function display_timer(seconds) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = seconds % 60;
    const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}`;
    timerDisplay.textContent = display;
}
  
restart.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    countdown = undefined;
    timerDisplay.textContent = '25:00';
  });
```

```css
.display_timer {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .control {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <title>pomodoro</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1 class="display_timer">25:00</h1> 
        
        <div class="control">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" data-action="start">START</button>   
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" data-action="restart">RESTART</button>
        </div>
        
    <script src="js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(Also as a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cqxn1Lwq/41/)

[image]

Comment: I've replaced your JSFiddle link with a 'Stack Snippet' so that people can run your code without leaving the site. This is encouraged when you're writing questions; try to do this in future, as you'll likely get better responses if people don't have to go to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an error while trying to format the display in the `display_timer()` function:

```
#>> const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}`;
```

You need to add the `remainderSeconds` after the test :

```
const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${remainderSeconds}`
```

```js
let countdown;

const timerDisplay = document.querySelector('.display_timer');
const start = document.querySelector('[data-action="start"]');
const restart = document.querySelector('[data-action="restart"]')

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (countdown) return;
    timer(1500);
});

function timer(seconds) {
    const now = Date.now();
    const then = now + (seconds * 1000);


    countdown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);
        if (secondsLeft < 0) {
          clearInterval(countdown);
          return;
          timer(1500);
        }
          display_timer(secondsLeft);
      }, 1000);
}
   
function display_timer(seconds) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = seconds % 60;
    const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${remainderSeconds}`;
    timerDisplay.textContent = display;
}
  
restart.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    countdown = undefined;
    timerDisplay.textContent = '25:00';
  });
```

```css
.display_timer {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .control {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <title>pomodoro</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1 class="display_timer">25:00</h1> 
        
        <div class="control">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" data-action="start">START</button>   
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" data-action="restart">RESTART</button>
        </div>
        
    <script src="js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo, change

```
const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}`;
```

to

```
const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${remainderSeconds}`;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that a typo, if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually add your seconds to you display. You need to change the display cost to include the seconds value in addition to the 0/empty prefix

```
function display_timer(seconds) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = seconds % 60;
    const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${remaiderSecods}`;
    timerDisplay.textContent = display;
}
```